# how to declare php array variable in javascript and view on datatable

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli, datatables

I get array values in `$dispatch` variable and also pass it through in JavaScript `var dataSet3=<?php echo json_encode($dispatch); ?>;`  but my data table is showing only one row when array contains two rows.

SQL query:

```
$userSQL3 = "SELECT magazine.name_txt, dispatch.dispatch_id, dispatch.dispatch_dt, dispatch.notes_txt, dispatch_details.created_dt FROM dispatch_details left join dispatch on dispatch_id=fk_dispatch_id LEFT JOIN magazine ON magazine.magazine_id = dispatch.fk_magazine_id WHERE fk_subscriber_id = ". $subscriber_id;
 $usersResult3 = mysqli_query($dbConn, $userSQL3);
while($userResult3 = mysqli_fetch_array($usersResult3))
{      
 $dispatch=array($userResult3) ;

   echo"<pre>";
        print_r($dispatch);
    echo"</pre>";
}
```

JavaScript code:

```
var dataSet3=<?php echo json_encode($dispatch); ?>;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dispatch').DataTable( {
        searching: false,
        paging:false,
        bLengthChange:false,
        data: dataSet3,
        columns: [
            { data: "fk_dispatch_id" ,"visible": false},
            { data: "fk_subscriber_id" ,"visible": false },
            { data: "created_dt"  },
            { data: "updated_dt" ,"visible": false},
            { data: "dispatch_id" },
            { data: "dispatch_dt" },
            { data: "fk_publisher_id","visible": false },
            { data: "name_txt" },
            { data: "notes_txt" },
            { data: "created_dt" ,"visible": false },
            { data: "updated_dt" ,"visible": false}
        ],
    } );
} );
```

Comment: @Anant  in a array view get the values but datatable not showing values!

Comment: did var dataset3 contains the required json?

Comment: @Anant the link using ajax but i was directly pass through the values js to datatables :- https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html

Comment: @ArunKumaresh sry i'm beginner so more  know about json like that

Comment: @Anant yes i got following error:-*sub.php:111 GET https:cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTa%3Chead%3Ebles.min.css
sub.php is my file name

Comment: i think the problem is with json check whether you have valid json in dataset3

Comment: @Anant that console error is css error..i was solve it...but now console no error

Comment: @ArunKumaresh yes friend ,i think also that json part but the json remove to not get the variable values

Comment: console.log(dataset3) and see what your getting in the dataset3 variable

Comment: @ArunKumaresh console.log(dataset3) get no error but this get only one array row values,the second row value not get it

Comment: Again a hard-coded example for you (working at my end):-https://eval.in/645762   .check the HTML, java-script and libraries + json structure and change accordingly. For more support :- https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html

Comment: @Anant not displayed  the array values.only displayed by table headers only..

Comment: Try JSON.parse(dataSet3);

Comment: @Prasanna  why don't you go with the dattable example link that i have given to you.? I am sorry but only that much help i can do.

Comment: @Anant the output becomes following url
http://ekattanam.com/atelier/prasanna/image/Untitled.png

Comment: @Dmytrechko  jason.parse comes error.unexpected token

Comment: @Prasanna read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the corrected code below.

**PHP**

```php
$userSQL3 = "SELECT magazine.name_txt, dispatch.dispatch_id, dispatch.dispatch_dt, dispatch.notes_txt, dispatch_details.created_dt FROM dispatch_details left join dispatch on dispatch_id=fk_dispatch_id LEFT JOIN magazine ON magazine.magazine_id = dispatch.fk_magazine_id WHERE fk_subscriber_id = ". $subscriber_id;
$usersResult3 = mysqli_query($dbConn, $userSQL3);

$dispatch = array();
while($userResult3 = mysqli_fetch_array($usersResult3, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{      
    array_push($dispatch, $userResult3); 
}
```